# Routes issue with Static Pages Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have two home pages for two user types: home.html.erb (for users) and shop_home.html.erb (for shops). When I click the home link in the site header while a "user" is logged in, it routes the user to home.html.erb through the home method in the static pages controller.  I'm having trouble routing to shop_user.html.erb though.  The shop_home route isn't working.

**shop_header.erb**

```
<% if shop_logged_in? %>
  <li id="blacklink"><%= link_to "Home", shop_home %></li>
  <li id="blacklink"><%= link_to "Drivers", users_path %></li>
  <li id="blacklink"><%= link_to "Log out", shop_logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>  
<% end %>
```

Clicking the "Home" link gives me `undefined local variable or method 'shop_home'`
What do I have to do to get the Home link to route to `shop_home.html.erb`?

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'shop_sessions/new'

  get 'shops/new'

  get 'cars/new'

  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'shophome' => 'static_pages#shop_home', as:"shop_home"
  get 'shop', to: 'static_pages#shop_home', as: 'shop_root'
  get 'shops', to: 'shops#index', as: 'shop_index'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'shopsignup' => 'shops#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  get    'shoplogin'   => 'shop_sessions#new', as: 'shop_login'
  post   'shoplogin'   => 'shop_sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  delete 'shoplogout'  => 'shop_sessions#destroy', as: 'shop_logout'

  resources :users
  resources :shops
  resources :cars,  only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
end
```

**staticpagescontroller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if logged_in?
      @car = current_user.cars.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def shop_home
    @shop = current_shop
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `_path` to the end of your defective `link_to`.

So change this line:

```
  <li id="blacklink"><%= link_to "Home", shop_home %></li>
```

To this:

```
  <li id="blacklink"><%= link_to "Home", shop_home_path %></li>
```